# PHP json loop with "." in value

Tags: php

I have already search here but can't finde any questions regrading this actually problem.

i got this code which is working until i have to phase the "lock.status" because of the "." the code fails and the json is coming from another site so i can't change it to be "_" or something else. So how can i use "." in this code?

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($result);
foreach ($jsonObject->result as $data) {
    echo $data->lock.status;
}
```

Comment: Alternative to the answer below is adding `true` to the 2nd param of `json_decode()`, e.g `json_decode($result, true)` which will return an array instead of an object. Then you can access the value by `$data['lock.status']` which looks nicer in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `{}` to allow you to use a string as an object key.

```
echo $data->{'lock.status'};
```